# Internet explorer issue, fonts, glyphicons, and font awesome get ignored over HTTPS

Tags: internet-explorer

In internet explorer, when I load my pages with HTTPS then the fonts, glyphicons and font awesome classes get ignored.

After a lot of searching, I set the cache-control to public but it did not work.
I have understood that internet explorer ignores the fonts etc as it does not stores the cache

Please help me to understand how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you share the response headers of your site and the font-awesome request as well?  Also what is the version of Internet Explorer you are using?

Comment: Hi SmileIT

Thanks for the reply

My response headers are:

        Accept Ranges: bytes
       Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-validate
       Connection: keep-alive
       content-length:669
       expires:0

Font awesome request:
its headers are same too

IE version is 11

I added this to my Head tag:
           <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
And I am using angular-cli

Plz let me know if you require something else is required

Comment: What is your css/ font include URL look like currently? Does it have a version number as part of the string? Also, are you including the IE font of fontawesome-webfont.eot in your source?

Comment: hi
I use font-awesome etc through angular-cli , by copying it in my file and references it through angular-cli.json

Comment: Are you using font-awesome via references to your own server or are you referencing them via a third-party CDN? If you are serving the files you need to serve up an empty or remove pragma and cache-control header for font files/css.

Comment: I am not using any cdn. I have added all the bootstrap(+glyphicon fonts), font awesome(+css) in my own project and referenced through angular-cli.json

Comment: hi can u elaborate this " you are serving the files you need to serve up an empty or remove pragma and cache-control header for font files/css"??

Comment: My .woff and .woff2 (webfont) files are being served through http with the above mentioned response headers while the font-awesome/bootstrap.css are being embeedded into my index.html directly as I am loading them directly from my directory.

Comment: After researching more on this, I have got familiar with the fact that the issue is caused by cache-control: no-store and pragma: no-cache that forms the response headers of my .woff and .woff2 files....Now, I am using angular 2 app with spring boot backend, I am not able to understand how to remove these from the response headers ..... ad do I need to remove the same from index.html response headers too???

Comment: + .eot files for IE

Comment: What kind of web server are you running? If you are running apache you can add some setting to .htaccess. <FilesMatch "\.(eot|woff|woff2)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>

Comment: Not using apache.... Can i do the above with spring boot?

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring Boot but since it is Java based I am guessing you have a Jetty or Tomcat server running??? There are a number of pages on this site that outline how to set/unset/disable unwanted http headers.